# how to connect two projects Laravel 4.2 and laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.5

i have a laravel 4.2 project that i want to connect it to laravel 5.5 project

Q1) how to login in the first and and authenticated to the second to so i don't have to login to the second

Q2)how to connect them to the same DB

Q3)let's say i'm in page X in laravel 4.2 and i want to direct it to Y in laravel 5.5 where i should write the route in laravel 4.2 or in 5.5 ?

at the end both of the projects are going to be on the same server and have the same domain if that is going to be helpful

Comment: yes they are going to be on the same domain

Comment: It really sounds like you need bring them under one application if they're on the same domain. Unless theres more information you can give that would justify the separation of the two apps. Setting up authentication and shared database between the apps could very quickly become a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) how to login in the first and and authenticated to the second to so i don't have to login to the second

> if the 2 webapp are in the same domain, it should not be an issue
>   especially if they use the same database.

Q2)how to connect them to the same DB

> just use the same credentials and save it on each env file.

Q3)let's say i'm in page X in laravel 4.2 and i want to direct it to Y in laravel 5.5 where i should write the route in laravel 4.2 or in 5.5 ?

> you can use the function route instead use the manual routing like
>   to('somepage-on-theother-laravel') this is a tedious work. So i want
>   to ask if why are you using the 2 webapp in the same domain instead of
>   just using 1 webapp framework. Im thinking that this laravel 4.2 is
>   the existing one and you're create a new one and you want to use the
>   laravel 5.5 right?

Comment: yes i have an existed project on laravel 4.2 and i wanted to upgrade it to 5.5 but there is no time for that now so i think if can start a new project of laravel 5.5 and add some features on it and make it work with the old one

Comment: Wait, what? Just asking that we on the same page: you have a 4.2 project and a 5.5 project which should be available under the same domain, lets say 
 example.com.

If this is correct, how do you decide which one answers the server request?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do, just put both applications on the same server and link them using the same credentials in the .ENV file, don't forget you will also need to create Models in both apps so that both apps can use the tables.

As for the routes, you would need to add the routes & functions that can be called in each individual app.

So if the user clicks the URL for /link-to-4.2 you should have a route in 4.2:

```
Route::get('/link-to-4.2', 'index@controller');
```

and then in your 5.5 you should have a route for any URLs that direct to anything there. i.e: /link-to-5.5

```
    Route::get('/link-to-5.5', 'index@controller');
```

this all being said, what is the justification for using 2 apps? I think there could be a number of security issues that might cause headaches, this will also likely be a real nightmare to manage moving forward.

I would strongely suggest that you just upgrade the 4.2 app to be 5.5.

Comment: yes i have an existed project on laravel 4.2 and i wanted to upgrade it to 5.5 but there is no time for that now so i think if can start a new project of laravel 5.5 and add some features on it and make it work with the old one 

but i have a question can i upgrade to 5.5 with the same code in the 4.2 
?

Comment: It depends what is in the app and what packages you use, there are likely some depreciated features or parts might have a different format, i.e: the providers & aliases are in a different format between 4.2 & 5.5. This being said, if it's not a complex app, it should be straight forward to upgrade and will likely be a case of creating the controller, copy the functions from 4.2 into 5.5 and then add the route but it really depends on how complex your 4.2 app is.